# SARG with no records found

Tags: squid

I want to use sarg tool in linux centOS to report users using website. But when  installed, and when Iuse command `sarg -x -z`, the output is:

```
SARG: Init
SARG: Loading configuration from /usr/local/etc/sarg.conf
SARG: TAG: access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
SARG: TAG: output_dir /var/www/html/squid-reports
SARG: TAG: date_format e
SARG: TAG: overwrite_report yes
SARG: Parameters:
SARG:           Hostname or IP address (-a) = 
SARG:                    Useragent log (-b) = 
SARG:                     Exclude file (-c) = 
SARG:                  Date from-until (-d) = 
SARG:    Email address to send reports (-e) = 
SARG:                      Config file (-f) = /usr/local/etc/sarg.conf
SARG:                      Date format (-g) = Europe (dd/mm/yyyy)
SARG:                        IP report (-i) = No
SARG:                        Input log (-l) = /var/log/squid/access.log
SARG:               Resolve IP Address (-n) = No
SARG:                       Output dir (-o) = /var/www/html/squid-reports/
SARG: Use Ip Address instead of userid (-p) = No
SARG:                    Accessed site (-s) = 
SARG:                             Time (-t) = 
SARG:                             User (-u) = 
SARG:                    Temporary dir (-w) = /tmp/sarg
SARG:                   Debug messages (-x) = Yes
SARG:                 Process messages (-z) = Yes
SARG: 
SARG: sarg version: 2.3.1 Sep-18-2010
SARG: Reading access log file: /var/log/squid/access.log
SARG: Records in file: 0, reading: 100.00%
SARG:    Records read: 0, written: 0, excluded: 0
SARG: No records found
SARG: End
```

And this is /var/log/squid/

```
root@FW sarg]# ll /var/log/squid/
total 184
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid     0 Jul 25 03:49 access.log
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid 12592 Jul 14 03:16 access.log-20130714
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid   208 Jul 25 03:49 access.log-20130725
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid  6944 Sep  3 12:56 cache.log
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid  1286 Aug  4 03:37 cache.log-20130804.gz
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid   168 Aug 11 03:22 cache.log-20130811.gz
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid   929 Aug 18 03:48 cache.log-20130818.gz
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid  1285 Aug 25 03:41 cache.log-20130825.gz
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid  1301 Sep  1 13:24 cache.log-20130901.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root   6517 Jul 25 08:51 squid.out
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid 13968 Sep  4 13:56 store.log
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid 32398 Aug  4 03:37 store.log-20130804
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid 32592 Aug 11 03:22 store.log-20130811
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid 30652 Aug 18 03:48 store.log-20130818
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid  6180 Aug 25 03:41 store.log-20130825.gz
-rw-r-----  1 squid squid  5763 Sep  1 13:24 store.log-20130901.gz
```

And this is `sarg.conf`

```
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
output_dir /var/www/html/squid-reports
overwrite_report yes
.....
```

and reports in web

```
My Squid User Access Reports     FILE/PERIOD    CREATION
DATE    USERS   BYTES   AVERAGE 24Jul2013-24Jul2013 Wed 24 Jul 2013 03:04:28 PM
ICT 1   5.57K   5.57K 21Jul2013-25Jul2013   Thu 25 Jul 2013 09:30:37 AM
ICT 0       0 14Jul2013-25Jul2013   Thu 25 Jul 2013 10:35:22 AM
ICT 1   5.57K   5.57K Generated by sarg-2.3.1 Sep-18-2010 on
25/Jul/2013-10:35
```

This is very little information. How can I increase that?

Answer (score 1):

your log file size is zero since from July 25, that's why you are facing this issue

```
-rw-r-----. 1 squid squid     0 Jul 25 03:49 access.log
```

So just check your disk space and inode, may be because of this squid is unable to generate logs